# How not to reload footer on page navigation

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have music application in which I have simple player in footer. User can choose songs from main page list and play it in footer. Now requirement is even if user moves fro home page to other pages(profile, bookmarks) in application the footer player should not get reloaded and should keep playing audio selected on home page initially.

How do I do that? DO I need to load pages through ajax?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that development is 80% completed and footer reloads on every page load. How much of rework is needed if I have to use Ajax now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PJAX. Reload just the parts of the page that you want: https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails

It's already integrated with Rails and everything you put outside of this block will not be reloaded:

```
<div data-pjax-container>
  <!-- PJAX updates will go here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution similar to PJAX and Turbolinks

https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks

Answer (score 1):

Some very good answers already, but i just wanted to explain your problem better.

HTTP requests is "stateless", which means that each request are fully independent and their is no way you can know anything about how the page was before you requested a new page. This makes it impossible not to reload the footer on each request, using only HTTP.

You can use cookies to keep information between request, so you could start the player where it stopped before the request, but it will still reload (and stop for a short duration).

You can also have the rest of the page in a iframe, and only change the content of the iframe.

However these solutions is not very good for various reasons, so i would strongly recommend the last and best solution: ajax.

The simples solution is properly [pjax](https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails) as @aledalgrande suggested (or [wiselink](https://github.com/igor-alexandrov/wiselinks) as suggested by @adbeel). This will i practice make your site a "one-site-application" where you use ajax to replace specific parts of the page instead of the whole page. It should however be fairly simple to integrate, even in a existing rails application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you put jQuery as a tag I suggest you either look at http://api.jquery.com/load/.

Answer (score 0):

You can using plain old HTML and making it easier & faster to deploy since the app is almost 'done'. Later you should implement a better (ajax) option.

Simplified: **index.html**

```
<iframe id="mainframe" src="other.html"></iframe>
<footer>
    Don't reload me pls :D
</footer>
```

on page navigation (links) you act only on the mainframe, leaving the footer not reloaded.

**NOTE:** This is *ugly* and <del>*may*</del> will give you problems but might serve you to do minimal modification and having your site live asap.

Then rewriting the whole thing to using ajax could be 'some work required' to 'heavy work required' depending on how the app is already implemented. note that **will never be** 'few or no work required'.